# Relative div overlaps parent table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with div which placed inside of table cell. 
Cell has fixed height and div positioned relative with height:100%.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PHBfd/8/)

```
td {
    height:80px;
    width: 80px;
}
.cell_text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

[image]

The problem appears when i change div's content and div height becomes greater than cell height. Behavior for IE and FF is below:

[image]

And the following picture illustrates Chrome's behavior:

[image]

Chrome's behavior is exactly what I need, how can I make it work same way in IE and Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

I removed unnecessary markup and CSS, and now it seems to work fine.

`position: relative` did not really make much sense, and the `border-fix` div seemed to be unnecessary - and also caused the problem. Tables (and elements having `display: table-cell` and the likes) are quite flexible when it comes to `height` - simple block elements may not be, like in this case.

There was a lot of redundant CSS also, please see [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHBfd/11/). Tested in Chrome, FF, IE9.

So this would be the markup:

```
<td class="border">
    <div class="cell_wrapper">
        <div class="cell_text">
            line-1
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
#mytable td {
    height:80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

.cell_wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.cell_text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. unfortunately there is another one problem with div placed inside adjacent cells: http://jsfiddle.net/PHBfd/12/. it's height doesn't change.

Comment: @user947668 Hm, that's quite bad... the problem with table cells is that you cannot use the `position: relative` & stretching by positioning absolutely trick. And it seems like in some browsers `height: 100%` relates to the originally set `height` (correctly, I assume). Maybe you have no other choice but rethink this whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox offers some possibilities for controlling cell behaviors, but if you have to support IE7, you're out of luck.  `display: table-cell;` doesn't work in IE7 or earlier.

Comment: This should have been a comment, it does not even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Still kind of new to posting here.  Thanks for the tip!